# Filter array of arrays in Julia by simple command

Tags: julia

I have an array of two arrays like this

`x = [[1.5, 2.5], [3.5, 4.5]]`

where the two inner arrays always have equal length.

I want to apply a filter in a pairwise manner. The pairs in the above example would be `[1.5, 3.5]` and `[2.5, 4.5]`. The filter criterium should be to select a pair if both elements are larger than a critical value, say 2. The result should be again in the original form, i.e.

`result = [[2.5],[4.5]]`

Another example would be

`x = [[1.5, 2.5, 3.5], [4.5, 5.5, 6.5]]` -> `result = [[2.5, 3.5], [5.5, 6.5]]`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: whats your rule of filtering?

Comment: For example, x= x[[x1,x2],[y1,y2]]. If x1 or x2 >2 --> My result.

Comment: Are you sure you mean to have a 2-array of 2-arrays rather than a single 2x2 array? I suspect you meant to write `x = [[1.5 2.5];[3.5 4.5]]` instead

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: yes. I'm sure. I want to do with 2-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1} instead of 2×2 Array{Float64,2}

Comment: Your question is still too broad. What would be your intended output for `x = [[1.5, 2.5, 3.5], [4.5, 5.5, 6.5]]`?

Comment: Sorry for the not clear question. My expected output will be x=[[2.5, 3.5], [5.5, 6.5]].

Comment: At first I thought you ment something like `filter.(y->y>2, x)` but it seems you don't.

Comment: Sorry, but I downvoted.  This question needs to be cleaned up.  I'd try to clean it up myself, but I'm still not sure what the original intent was.  Currently, I don't see how anyone else will learn from this question, other than that there are lots of possible answers for ambiguous questions.  Fix it and I'll upvote.

Comment: Since @LemLam accepted my answer and stated below that it does what he wants I'll take the freedom to cleanup the question.

Comment: @crstnbr OK, but I'm still wondering about his desired logic here.  He says in a comment "If x1 or x2 >2 --> My result", but then he accepted your `&&` logic.

Comment: I know. But from his examples it's clear that it can't be x1 or x2 > 2. Anyway, I think enough has been written here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of guessing your precise filter criterium, one option would be

```
julia> using SplitApplyCombine

julia> x = [[1.5, 2.5, 3.5], [4.5, 5.5, 6.5]];

julia> invert(filter(y->y[1]>2&&y[2]>2, invert(x)))
2-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [2.5, 3.5]
 [5.5, 6.5]
```

Not that the method [`invert`](https://github.com/JuliaData/SplitApplyCombine.jl/blob/master/src/invert.jl#L27) is defined in the external package [SplitApplyCombine.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/SplitApplyCombine.jl) which you have to add first (`] add SplitApplyCombine`).

However, a straight forward for-loop implementation would work as well and would probably be faster.

Answer (score 0):

To keep any but the first element

```
julia> x = [[1.5, 2.5, 3.5], [4.5, 5.5, 6.5]];

julia> (x->x[2:end]).(x)
2-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [2.5, 3.5]
 [5.5, 6.5]
```

Comment: Same as `shift!`, yes?

Answer (score -1):

Let me straight it out. As my expected, I want to filter from 2-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1} with a critical value. For example, my critical value is 2 for x[1]. And my input is 
x= [[1.5,2.5,3.5,0.5],[3,4,5,6]].
My expected result should be
x= [[2.5, 3.5],[4,5]].
Is it clear for you guys?

Comment: This should be an edit of your question and not an answer. It's still not clear though as no one could possibly know what you mean by critical value. Did you look at my answer? What is it doing wrong? Did you try to adjust it yourself? You got a lot of input from the given answers.

Comment: See. thanks @crstnbr. That is expected answer for my question.